# Link de Fancybox no funciona

Tags: popup, ventana, bootstrap

estoy implementando un fancybox con boostrap 4 cuando arranca la pagina con un enlace a otra pagina. El fancybox funciona bien, pero el link no funciona. Pense que era un z-index pero aun así no sale:

Estilos internos del fancybox:

```
<style>
#consolPopup {
    display: none;
    width: 800px !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#consolPopup img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.fancybox-skin {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.fancybox-content {
    background: none !important;
}
.fancybox-slide--html .fancybox-close-small {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.fancybox-button svg {
    color: black;
}
#popup {
    z-index: 1500px;
}
</style>
```

Etiqueta Body

```
<body>
<div id="popup"> <a href="presentacion-de-expositores.html" target="_parent"><img src="img/popup-presentaciones.jpg" width="600" height="646" alt=""/></a> </div>
```

Script Antes del Body

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
            $(document).ready(function() {        
                $("#popup").fancybox().trigger('click');     
            });
            </script>
```

Pueden ver la pagina [aca](https://elgatodiego.com/clientes/acrip/)

¿Hay otra forma de hacerlo ?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo puede solucionar ...

```html
<div id="popup"> 
    <iframe src="popup.html" scrolling="no" height="600" width="600"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Lo pueden ver [aca](https://elgatodiego.com/clientes/acrip/)